# Where's my Dumpling? (err... dupe-link)

Tags: bug, duplicate-questions, closed-questions

I was visiting [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/807939/2173917), and I see it's closed as dupe. Ok, Good.

Then I noticed, the banner announcing the dupe-link, is entirely missing!!

Is it actually the link(banner) is missing or is it me who's missing something?

[image]

*P.S- Sorry for not having enough free hand red-circles, added free hand free-forms, instead.*

Comment: @AlonEitan Yep, should be the same. But it looks like it was never added. Am I wrong?

Comment: I don't think it's the same. Here it was never added in the first place.

Comment: @Floern .....and a suggestion to add the same was rejected...so I guess it was never added, that is what surprises me...

Comment: So maybe the duplicate was deleted (I don't know if this can happen)?

Comment: @AlonEitan No, both dupe targets still exist. The two comments link to the and you can see them in the edit history even though they were never added in.

Comment: The question closed as a duplication of this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240212/what-is-the-difference-between-new-delete-and-malloc-free

Comment: @SagarV that is evident from the comment...but my question was, why the banner was not showing up...and the linked dupe answers that.

Comment: @SouravGhosh I think Sagar V was providing the link for Alon, who asked if the duplicates were deleted.

Comment: Ah, so as @BSMP wrote, this behaviour match to the accepted answer in the possible duplicate _"In the beginning, when people voted to close as duplicate, they were not prompted for a target.
**It was assumed it was already mentioned in the comments** (as is the case here, see the last two comments)."_

Comment: Interestingly... "for science" the duplicate links are still editable... see [latest revision](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/807939/revisions) but it doesn't cause a banner to be introduced (kind of figured it wouldn't though...)

Comment: Where did you find the "hook" to edit the duplicate links, @Jon? If the duplicate banner isn't displayed, there is no link displayed in the UI. Did you use the mod tools, or URL manipulation?

Comment: @CodyGray manually put in the URL`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/originals/<question_id>/edit`

Comment: @JonClements You mean `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/originals/807939/edit`? I get a 404.

Comment: @SouravGhosh yes... but you have to have a gold badge in one of the tags to edit duplicate targets...

Comment: @JonClements Ahh...its' C++, I see.